# Loading spinner not working correctly in next screen in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am new in **Compose Navigation**. I have **Button** and when I clicked, I called the function in **Viewmodel** and trigger loading event with using **StateFlow**. So I called the next screen through navigation and calling loading spinner. I used `delay(5000)` to show spinner more before getting data but spinner is loading after the data is loaded. Can someone guide me.

**MainActivityViewModel.kt**

```
class MainActivityViewModel(private val resultRepository: ResultRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val stateResultFetchState = MutableStateFlow<ResultFetchState>(ResultFetchState.OnEmpty)

    fun getSportResult() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.IsLoading
            val result = resultRepository.getSportResult()
            delay(5000)
            result.handleResult(
                onSuccess = { response ->
                    if (response != null) {
                        stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.OnSuccess(response)
                    } else {
                        stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.OnEmpty
                    }
                },
                onError = {
                    stateResultFetchState.value =
                        ResultFetchState.OnError(it.errorResponse?.errorMessage)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**SetupMainActivityView.kt**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SetupMainActivityView(
    viewModel: MainActivityViewModel = koinViewModel(),
    navigateToNext: () -> Unit,
) {
    Scaffold(topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)) },
            backgroundColor = getBackgroundColor(),
            elevation = 0.dp
        )
    }, content = { padding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(getBackgroundColor())
                .padding(padding),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Button(onClick = {
                viewModel.getSportResult()
            }) {
                Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.get_result))
            }
        }
    })
    when (val state = viewModel.stateResultFetchState.collectAsState().value) {
        is ResultFetchState.OnSuccess -> {}
        is ResultFetchState.IsLoading -> {
            navigateToNext()
        }
        is ResultFetchState.OnError -> {}
        is ResultFetchState.OnEmpty -> {}
    }
}
```

My whole project [link](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult). Can someone guide me how can I show loading spinner after loading the next screen. Thanks

**UPDATE**

**NavigationGraph.kt**

```
@Composable
internal fun NavigationGraph() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = ScreenRoute.Home.route) {
        composable(ScreenRoute.Home.route) {
            SetupMainActivityView{
                navController.navigate(ScreenRoute.Result.route)
            }
        }

        composable(ScreenRoute.Result.route) {
            ResultScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

**ResultScreen.kt**

```
@Composable
fun ResultScreen() {
    CircularProgressIndicator()
}
```

please check my repository if you need more code. I added my github link above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your code handling the Spinner. Anyway, a general idea to handle these kinda situations is

```
val state = remember{mutableStateOf<ResultFetchState>(ResultFetchState.EMPTY)}

if(state == ResultFetchState.LOADING){
  //show spinner
   Spinner()
}

...

state.value = viewModel.stateResultFetchState.collectAsState().value
```

Comment: why do use `remember` ?

Comment: @vivekmodi It retains the state's value with the composable's recomposition.

Comment: I added my whole code can you please check.

Comment: In your code how are you changing the state ?

Comment: please check my **viewmodel** how `viewModel.stateResultFetchState` this is changing.